# SQL get records by date filter

Tags: mysql, sql

I need get date by date filters: Last 10 days, Last 30 days, Last 12 monthes.
I coded it:

For last 10 days:

```
SELECT  * FROM INVOICES  WHERE invoices.date>= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -10 DAY);
```

Last 30 days:

```
SELECT  * FROM INVOICES  WHERE invoices.date>= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -30 DAY);
```

Last 12 monthes:

```
SELECT  * FROM INVOICES  WHERE invoices.date>= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -12 MONTH);
```

Please give me comments if it is correct way to select data by date filters?

Comment: your dbms name please

Comment: Yes, this looks valid.  Have you tried running these queries yet?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine and is perfectly valid. I only have some stylistic reccomendation based upon my own preferences.

I would recommend you using it like this, by substracting the interval from the curdate() date, it makes it seem a bit more logical to a reader, you substract a set of days from the current day to get a date in the past.
Instead of thinking, I'm adding a negative amount of days/months, which will actually substract it, to the current date to get a date in the past.

```
 SELECT  * FROM invoices  WHERE invoices.date >= curdate() - INTERVAL 10 DAY 
 SELECT  * FROM invoices  WHERE invoices.date >= curdate() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
 SELECT  * FROM invoices  WHERE invoices.date >= curdate() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH
```

Comment: @Tschallacka . . . Absolutely not.  The recommendation to use `now()` instead of `curdate()` (or current_date) is actually ridiculous.  Do not introduce time components for date comparisons.

Comment: sometimes you need minute precision, but whatever, I modified it to curdate @GordonLinoff happy now?

Answer (score 0):

The code that you wrote is perfectly fine and should probably do well in your case.
However, one thing that I'd advise you about dates and their functions is essentially this - **when you issue i.e. date function such as `now()` or `curdate()` your query result cannot be cached**.

Results of such query cannot be cached and reused and this is crucial in case of large data sets. As long as you are aware of this, you will be able to take care of potential adverse effects and tinker of a proper way to bypass this issue IF it's possible/desirable to cache the query results in your case.